# sql query to have all yes in a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, count, having

I'm trying to make a sql query to only have the "yes" value in a column named checked but it always return me "no" value too like this on Microsoft Access :

```
CHECKED | POINTS VUS
NULL    | 4
YES     | 4
```

If anyone could help me . Thank you very much. Here is my query :

```
SELECT
  CHECKED, 
  COUNT(*) AS `POINTS VUS`
FROM
  ARCHPOINTS
GROUP BY CHECKED 
HAVING COUNT(*) = yes
```

Comment: Please give a sample output.

Comment: It gives me this on access: checked | points vus
  yes | 4
  null | 5

Comment: Please update your question with sample input output in tabular form. It is little unclear what is your actual expectation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this =>

```
SELECT
  CHECKED,
  COUNT(*) AS `POINTS VUS`
FROM
  ARCHPOINTS
  WHERE CHECKED='yes'
  GROUP BY CHECKED
```